# Difference between Animal a = new Horse() and Horse c = new Horse()

Tags: java, inheritance

Assuming that `Horse` class is a subclass of `Animal` class.

- a and c both use methods and instance variables in `Horse` class
- c can use methods from `Animal` class too.
  So is there any difference between these 2 reference variables.

Thanks for any reply

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrong.
`a` cannot use methods only in the `Horse` class, because `a` is not declared as `Horse`.

Comment: +1 correct, unless casting `a` to `Horse`: `((Horse) a).methodFormHorseClass();`.

Comment: iff the extended class doesnt override an abstract method. if there is an abstract method or interface, a can invoke that method in horse class. In this case, Animal is also a class, but it can be an abstract class as well.

Comment: @DarthVader: But the method is also in `Animal`.

Answer (score 2):

One of them is to **program to an interface,** the other is to program to an instance.

With the first one:

```
Animal a = new Horse();
```

you can use this object anywhere where an animal instance is required, can be any kind of animal.

```
Animal d = new Dog();

public void MakeSound(Animal a)
{
 a.makeSound();
}
```

In this case , if your Animal class is abstract class (if the method is abstract) or an interface, you have to implment that method.

Whereas you have methods on Horse class, you can only use those methods if you use `Horse h = new Horse();`

Programming to an interface is preferred.

Comment: I was gonna answer trying to get out of the cliche *Animal makes sound* thing, but this example and explanation is good enough.. plus 1

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you should always prefer the least specific variable type compatible with its usage, just to make it easier to read. In practice, if you use a `List` var instead of `ArrayList`, it makes it obvious you don't need anything specific to `ArrayList` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The object `a` cannot reference methods/variables in `Horse` unless it is typecasted.

Answer (score 0):

Is Horse inherited from Animal?

If thats the case, you call Super.[a Method from animal]
and Horse.[a Method from horse only]

Horse can access all the methods from animal because they are inherited,
but animal cannot access methods from horse because they are specific for horse only.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important concepts to take a look here: the **static type** of a reference; which is the one it's been declared with; and the **runtime type** of a reference; which is the real type that the reference points to at runtime.

In your example, both variables have the runtime type `Horse`, but `a` has the static type `Animal`. This impacts the way you treat both variables in the code, where their **static type** is enforced  by the compiler; regardless of their runtime type.

So, even though they both reference `Horse` instances, only through `c` can you call `Horse`-specific methods (without casting or using reflection on `a`).